# endpoints common vs tenant id

Tags: oauth, active-directory, office365, exchangewebservices

I am developing a python app running on embedded linux to access office365 calendar via the EWS interface. I plan on using impersonation to access data.

I have registered my app with azure AD and retrieved the endpoints which contain a tenant id.  But I have learned that using the common endpoint seems to work just fine in refreshing the access token.

what are the advantages or limitations in using the tenant id instead of just using common?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant/.  The common endpoint does late binding to the tenant based on the users login details.  The article does add "For line of business applications you do NOT want to late bind the tenant, in fact you want to ensure that the caller comes from your specific tenant and no other! In that case, use of common is not appropriate."

Comment: That would be great if using tenant was working and not giving an error:
 
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'APP_CLIENT_ID' named 'APP_CLIENT_NAME'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.